# Docker-Compose - ASP.NET app not able to resolve DNS

Tags: windows-container

I am trying to run ASP.NET application with SQL server in windows container using docker compose. 
I am able to ping SQL container IP from asp.net container however not able to connect through alias name. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

My compose file:

```
version: '3'

#services details
services:
  contosouniversity:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    expose:
      - "5000"
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    depends_on: 
      - university_db

#data base details
  university_db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer
    environment:
      sa_password: "sa"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "5672:1433"

#network configuration
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

ASP.NET web.config file has connection string:

```
<add name="SchoolContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=university_db;Initial Catalog=ContosoUniversity2;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Password=sa" 
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Login into running containers via `docker exec` and try to resolve name from powershell prompt

Comment: Hey Thanks for quick response. I tried but its failing. Please find log below:C:\inetpub\wwwroot>ping university_db
Ping request could not find host university_db. Please check the name and try again.


C:\inetpub\wwwroot>nslookup 74fa1763a1e9
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  172.25.208.1

*** UnKnown can't find 74fa1763a1e9: Server failed

C:\inetpub\wwwroot>hostname
5d1a40194c9f

C:\inetpub\wwwroot>nslookup 5d1a40194c9f
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  172.25.208.1

*** UnKnown can't find 5d1a40194c9f: Server failed

Comment: Appreciate if anyone can answer.. I am really stuck

Comment: I suggest join `windows-containers` slack channel, you will get response there faster. Sample compose file below works fine for me for name resolution ```version: '3'

#services details
services:
  contosouniversity:  
    image: microsoft/iis:nanoserver
    depends_on: 
      - university_db

#data base details
  university_db:
    image: microsoft/iis:nanoserver

#network configuration
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat

Comment: The issue got resolved.. I think issue happened because I had installed DNS and DHCP server on same machine.. I did fresh installation of windows server and docker... it's working fine now...  thanks for your help...